# Swing: In Jtable when cursor move down the JScroll bar also should move down?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, awtrobot

I am using JTable when user double click on the row then mouse should foucs on next row. -> ok
At the time scroll bar how to move Jscrollbar & mouse at same poistion

```
public void TableMouseListener implements MouseListener {


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            //if the double click is performed or left button
  if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) && e.getClickCount() >= 2) {

    Robot r;
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    JTable table = (JTable) e.getSource();
    int rowNumber = table.rowAtPoint(p);
    PointerInfo a1 = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b1 = a1.getLocation();
    int x1 = (int) b1.getX();
    int y1 = (int) b1.getY();
    System.out.println(x1+" :X :  "+x1);
    System.out.println(y1+" : Y : "+y1);

    //Mouse move to next record based row height                
    r = new Robot();
    r.mouseMove(x1, y1 +table.getRowHeight());

    //Can any one suggest move the scrollbar based on the cursor move
    //Rectangle rect = viewport.getViewRect();
    //rect.y = rect.y + table.getRowHeight();
    //viewport.scrollRectToVisible(rect); -> IF scrollbar is used to move but not in next poistion
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}




                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

- set proper [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) to `JTable`
- add [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) instead of using `AWT.Robot`, have to test if is any row selected (.... >-1),
- have to test if isn't `1st.` or `last` row in the `JTables view`,
- change selection [table.setRowSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSelectionMode%28int%29)

Comment: When we double click on selected row the mouse should focus to next but selection should on selected row only. But problem when scrollpane is present at the time there is no releation with Jscrollpane & mouse to move.

Comment: Any suggestion how move the mouse & scrollbar same time?

Comment: there no isuse with moving JScrollBar with JTable continiously, everything is in rest of your code, something block built_in scrollable :-)